# Implementing bursts or spikes detection in a counter using Redis

Tags: redis

I wanna use Redis to keep track of certain numbers. Basically, they're counters. Is there a way to use Redis to sort of track the rate at which these counters increase?

For example, let's say a counter is being incremented at a rate of 10 per minute for the most of the time but suddenly it's being incremented at a rate of 40 per minute. How can I detect that?

Answer (score 0):

You cannot do that directly, but you can do that with a sorted set for example, with a bit of client side, or Lua based processing.

Let's say that you use a sorted set, for each time window you increment the value:

```
ZINCRBY mykey timestamp 1
```

Then you have a simple counter per timestamp.

When you want to analyze it, you can take a range by time with `ZRANGE` or `ZREVRANGE`, getting the scores by using `WITHSCORES`, and do some processing on the differences for detecting anomalies. There are many ways to do it, here's a link with a few pointers: https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/152644/what-algorithm-should-i-use-to-detect-anomalies-on-time-series